# How to pull data from another sheet and do multiple calculations?

Tags: excel

I am having an issue with getting `=SUM(IF(AND('Call Log'!D:D="Jan",'Call Log'!Q:Q="Yes"),1,0))` to work. I have moved the `)` around based on other guides of how it works to no avail.

I am trying to pull data from sheet2 column `C` to search for the specific string if it finds "Jan" in the column take the cells that are true go to column `N` and see if they are yes or no/true or false, and for every true +1.

Comment: You may be looking for [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e): `=SUMPRODUCT(--('Call Log'!D:D="Jan"),--('Call Log'!Q:Q="Yes"))` will give you the count of rows where `D:D` = "Jan" and `Q:Q` = "Yes"

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no clue about SUMPRODUCT so this was an amazing treat for today.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried switching to single quotes?

Comment: I did, thanks for the help I needed to use SUMPRODUCT and then it all fell into place.